# How to handle pop-up window using Selenium? ("driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);" not working consistently)

Tags: selenium

We are facing some issue in switching to new window after clicking on the *link/button*

I was using the below code for switching to new window.

```
elem.click();
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); }
```

Observed that scripts runs inconsistently, It will be great if i get some consistent code for switching to new window. I feel there is a synchronization issue while switching to new window.

Comment: Have you tried waiting a bit? Maybe the window is not there when you're checking for it to be there

Comment: Please use wait after click on element and before window opens.

Comment: Please use wait as suggested @HelpingHands, also try to upload all possible code and the respective HTML code snippet of the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If @HelpingHands suggestion will not work the problem may lies in the several handlers exist simultaneously
The following code may help:
When you create the driver please save the appropriated handler

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get(uri);
MainWinHandler = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Then in order to switch

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    if(!winHandle.equals(MainWinHandler))
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it works now..

Even adding wait after clicking on the element and before window opens works but not stable as loading page

Answer (score 0):

Tried to use in below mentioned format

```
`driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 
driver.get(uri); 
String parentWindowHandlerP = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
elem.click(); 
while (driver.getWindowHandles().size() < 2) { 
Thread.sleep(500); 
} 
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
for (String windowHandle : handles) { 
if (!windowHandle.equals(parentWindowHandlerP)) { driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
}
}`
```